# Paging and sorting after using a query used with JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL.
I'm having 2 table like this:

Book

| id | name | unitPrice | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book1 | 1.9 | 20 |
| 2 | book2 | 2.4 | 32 |
| 3 | book3 | 2.7 | 51 |
| 4 | book4 | 8.2 | 22 |
| 5 | book5 | 6.9 | 13 |

StockInStore

| id | storeName | bookid | numberInStock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | store1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | store2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | store3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | store1 | 2 | 14 |
| 5 | store3 | 2 | 10 |
| 6 | store2 | 3 | 20 |
| 7 | store3 | 4 | 12 |
| 8 | store1 | 5 | 6 |

Now after I join these two tables, I got a result like this:

| bookId | name | unitPrice | quantity | stockId | storeName | numberInStock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book1 | 1.9 | 20 | 1 | store1 | 10 |
| 1 | book1 | 1.9 | 20 | 2 | store2 | 2 |
| 1 | book1 | 1.9 | 20 | 3 | store3 | 3 |
| 2 | book2 | 2.4 | 32 | 4 | store1 | 14 |
| 2 | book2 | 2.4 | 32 | 5 | store3 | 10 |
| 3 | book3 | 2.7 | 51 | 6 | store2 | 20 |
| 4 | book4 | 8.2 | 22 | 7 | store3 | 12 |
| 5 | book5 | 6.9 | 13 | 8 | store1 | 6 |

Now I can order by bookId or unitPrice easily. However, I cannot separate them for pagination purposes as usual. For example, I want each page to only display information about 2 books. I expect page 1 to only return book1 and book2 (if I sort ascending based on bookId), which meaning I only need the data of the first 5 rows in the above table when I am on the 1st page and the data is being sorted based on bookId ascending while I will need the last 2 rows of that table if I want to display the information for the second page.

I tried to implement DENSE_RANK() but then I failed to sort them based on unitPrice.

My current query is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY "bookId") AS offset_
    FROM (
        SELECT "book"."id" AS "bookId"
            , "book"."name"
            , "book"."unitPrice"
            , "book"."quantity"
            , "stockInStore"."id" AS "stockId"
            , "stockInStore"."storeName"
            , "stockInStore"."numberInStock"
        FROM "book"
        INNER JOIN "stockInStore"
        ON (
            "book"."id" = "stockInStore"."bookId"
        )
    ) result
) result_offset
--pagination part
WHERE offset_ > 0
AND offset_ <= 2
--or using this if i want to change the page for example
--WHERE offset_ > 2
--AND offset_ <= 4
```

However I can't sort by unitPrice while still making the offset_ with DENSE_RANK(). The output of the query above might look like this.

| bookId | name | unitPrice | quantity | stockId | storeName | numberInStock | offset_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book1 | 1.9 | 20 | 1 | store1 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | book1 | 1.9 | 20 | 2 | store2 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | book1 | 1.9 | 20 | 3 | store3 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | book2 | 2.4 | 32 | 4 | store1 | 14 | 2 |
| 2 | book2 | 2.4 | 32 | 5 | store3 | 10 | 2 |

Has anyone encountered this or does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you also show us your current query, and also _specify_ the expected result?

Comment: Hey, edit your question instead of giving relevant(?) information in the comments section.

Comment: `
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY "bookId") AS offset_
 FROM (
  SELECT "book"."id" AS "bookId"
   , "book"."name"
   , "book"."unitPrice"
   , "book"."quantity"
   , "stockInStore"."id" AS "stockId"
   , "stockInStore"."storeName"
   , "stockInStore"."numberInStock"
  FROM "book"
  INNER JOIN "stockInStore"
  ON (
   "book"."id" = "stockInStore"."bookId"
  )
 ) result
) result_offset
--pagination part
WHERE offset_ > 0
AND offset_ <= 2
`
It will return the 1st 5 rows in the 3rd table I mentioned and the last 2 if I change the offset_ condition.

Comment: So sorry newbie as stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem, we're all here to learn.